# Bitvector32 and Bitarray in C#

Tags: c#, bitarray, bitvector

I wanted to know whether there are bitwise operators for Bitvector32 that operate in O(1) time. I am currently using BitArray of large sizes and using Bitwise And,Or and Not which operate in  O(size of bitarray).

I searched the internet for this but could not find an answer. Hope people here can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Converting a BitVector32 to an int is an O(1) operation. ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.data))
- Converting an int to a BitVector32 is an O(1) operation. ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2zxz5d6h))
- Executing a bitwise operation on an int is an O(1) operation.

Thus,

```
var vectorAnd = new BitVector32(vector1.Data & vector2.Data);
var vectorOr = new BitVector32(vector1.Data | vector2.Data);
var vectorNot = new BitVector32(~vector1.Data);
```

are all O(1) operations.

Comment: But i started using BitArray due to extension in size....is there any way i can use Bitvector32 with larger number of bits. Any structure implementation ,or a Bitvector of higher length that still goes O(1) in bit-wise operations

Comment: @Dynamite: I think what you are asking (performing a bitwise operation on an *unbounded* number of bits in O(1)) is impossible. Note that O(1) or O(n) does not say anything about performance, just about complexity. So, I would really urge you to *measure* if the BitArray is *really* the bottleneck of your application (if it is, using native operations on an uint64 might be the fastest way to go).

Answer (score 3):

Given that a `BitVector32` is always exactly 32 bits, there's no varying size to speak of - so how could any operation be expressed in terms of the size of the data?

Personally I've never found `BitVector32` a terribly pleasant type - I would usually probably just stick to a `UInt32` to represent 32 bits, and use the normal `&`, `|` etc operators.

If you're thinking of replacing your `BitArray` with a bunch of `BitVector32` values, that's still going to end up making each operation O(n). Fundamentally it's hard to avoid that, unless you actually store original values and operations, deferring the actual application of the operation - which will be *much* more complicated, and only end up making things better if you only access a small proportion of the results.

Comment: But i started using BitArray due to extension in size....is there any way i can use Bitvector32 with larger number of bits. Any structure implementation ,or a Bitvector of higher length that still goes O(1) in bit-wise operations.

Comment: @Dynamite: No. It would be illogical for that to be possible, for arbitrary sizes. You could easily implement a larger-but-fixed sized bit vector, e.g. BitVector64, BitVector128 with constant-time operations, but you couldn't make it expand arbitrarily and still have constant time - not without deferring the computation, which as I say will only help if you don't actually use most of the results. Heck, just *copying the bits* isn't going to be a constant-time operation.

Comment: How do I create a bitvector of larger size ..say Bitvector128

Comment: @Dynamite: You'd probably be best just creating a structure holding two `ulong` values internally. What API you put on top of that is up to you.

Comment: It's a shame that BitVector32 is so unwieldy. And besides, no matter how I tried to work with it, it always came up slower than just bit fiddling against a UInt32 manually.

Comment: BitVector32 is simply slow as hell, like said above, use uint and do it yourself. A simple benchmark shows uint = 1715ms, BitVector32 = 4447ms, where it would do 1.000.000 reads and writes. That's a BIG difference.