# HashSet<int> methods and bitwise operator equivalents

Tags: c#

A quick question [about hashsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-7.0) methods.

I was looking at [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND) was wondering if there is some kind of logical mapping between the bitwise operators and hashset methods?[image: bitwise operation to HashSet]

EDIT: Added mapping image for reference

Comment: Not exactly.  Simple set representations tended to be done with bits in the olden days, favoring minimal storage and levering processor instructions.  HashSet is much more advanced by not restricting the set element type.  You can still get it [the old way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731823/bitvector32-and-bitarray-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please don't link offsite for detail crucial to your question. Please rewrite so that all of the detail needed is in the text of the question and then link only to provide supporting evidence. Right now your question is too hard to actually determine what you're asking.

Comment: If you can fix the question, then I'll vote to re-open.

Comment: It feels like the image is a logical mapping between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following three member methods of the `HashSet<T>` generic collection class to perform logical *item-wise* operations between the `HashSet<T>` and an `IEnumerable<T>` collection:

### Union

[void UnionWith (IEnumerable other);](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.unionwith?view=net-7.0)

Change the content of the `HashSet<T>` to contain all elements existing in itself, the `other` collection, or both.

This is similar to a bit-wise `OR`. Difference is that the `HashSet<T>` is modified in-place.

### Intersection

[public void IntersectWith (IEnumerable other);](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.intersectwith?view=net-7.0)

Alter the `HashSet<T>` to contain only elements that are existing in that object and in the `other` collection.

This is similar to a bit-wise `AND`. Again, `HashSet<T>` is modified in-place.

### Symmetric Except

[public void SymmetricExceptWith (IEnumerable other);](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.symmetricexceptwith?view=net-7.0)

Alter the `HashSet<T>` in such a way that only items that are existing either in that set or in the `other` collection, but not both.

This corresponds to a bitwise `XOR` (exclusive OR) operation. Again, the set is changed in-place.

### No item-wise complement

There is no direct equivalent to bit-wise inversion or complement.